# Problemas con el Sticky Footer

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con el StickyFooter (clase `.contenedor`), hago el calculo (min.hieght 100vh - 70px) pero no queda abajo el footer, no se cual podria ser el problema?

Si alguien puede verlo y decirme que solucion le podria dar se lo agradeceria. Perdon por la desproligidad. gracias!

[Enlace a repo GITHUB](https://github.com/narodriguez27/resto.git)

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    

}

body{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='260' height='260' viewBox='0 0 260 260'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23ecf4ef' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath d='M24.37 16c.2.65.39 1.32.54 2H21.17l1.17 2.34.45.9-.24.11V28a5 5 0 0 1-2.23 8.94l-.02.06a8 8 0 0 1-7.75 6h-20a8 8 0 0 1-7.74-6l-.02-.06A5 5 0 0 1-17.45 28v-6.76l-.79-1.58-.44-.9.9-.44.63-.32H-20a23.01 23.01 0 0 1 44.37-2zm-36.82 2a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-3.1 1.56.89 1.79 1.31-.66a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .86.02l2.88-1.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.43 0l2.88 1.27a1 1 0 0 0 .85-.02l3.1-1.55-.89-1.79-1.42.71a3 3 0 0 1-2.56.06l-2.77-1.23a1 1 0 0 0-.4-.09h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.4.09l-2.78 1.23a3 3 0 0 1-2.56-.06l-2.3-1.15a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1L.9 19.22a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01zm0-2h-4.9a21.01 21.01 0 0 1 39.61 0h-2.09l-.06-.13-.26.13h-32.31zm30.35 7.68l1.36-.68h1.3v2h-36v-1.15l.34-.17 1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0L2.26 23h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.56.06l1.67-.74h3.23l1.67.74a3 3 0 0 0 2.56-.06zM-13.82 27l16.37 4.91L18.93 27h-32.75zm-.63 2h.34l16.66 5 16.67-5h.33a3 3 0 1 1 0 6h-34a3 3 0 1 1 0-6zm1.35 8a6 6 0 0 0 5.65 4h20a6 6 0 0 0 5.66-4H-13.1z'/%3E%3Cpath id='path6_fill-copy' d='M284.37 16c.2.65.39 1.32.54 2H281.17l1.17 2.34.45.9-.24.11V28a5 5 0 0 1-2.23 8.94l-.02.06a8 8 0 0 1-7.75 6h-20a8 8 0 0 1-7.74-6l-.02-.06a5 5 0 0 1-2.24-8.94v-6.76l-.79-1.58-.44-.9.9-.44.63-.32H240a23.01 23.01 0 0 1 44.37-2zm-36.82 2a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-3.1 1.56.89 1.79 1.31-.66a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .9 0l2.21-1.1a3 3 0 0 1 2.69 0l2.2 1.1a1 1 0 0 0 .86.02l2.88-1.27a3 3 0 0 1 2.43 0l2.88 1.27a1 1 0 0 0 .85-.02l3.1-1.55-.89-1.79-1.42.71a3 3 0 0 1-2.56.06l-2.77-1.23a1 1 0 0 0-.4-.09h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.4.09l-2.78 1.23a3 3 0 0 1-2.56-.06l-2.3-1.15a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01a1 1 0 0 0-.44.1l-2.21 1.11a3 3 0 0 1-2.69 0l-2.2-1.1a1 1 0 0 0-.45-.11h-.01zm0-2h-4.9a21.01 21.01 0 0 1 39.61 0h-2.09l-.06-.13-.26.13h-32.31zm30.35 7.68l1.36-.68h1.3v2h-36v-1.15l.34-.17 1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.69 0l1.36-.68h2.59l1.36.68a3 3 0 0 0 2.56.06l1.67-.74h3.23l1.67.74a3 3 0 0 0 2.56-.06zM246.18 27l16.37 4.91L278.93 27h-32.75zm-.63 2h.34l16.66 5 16.67-5h.33a3 3 0 1 1 0 6h-34a3 3 0 1 1 0-6zm1.35 8a6 6 0 0 0 5.65 4h20a6 6 0 0 0 5.66-4H246.9z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M159.5 21.02A9 9 0 0 0 151 15h-42a9 9 0 0 0-8.5 6.02 6 6 0 0 0 .02 11.96A8.99 8.99 0 0 0 109 45h42a9 9 0 0 0 8.48-12.02 6 6 0 0 0 .02-11.96zM151 17h-42a7 7 0 0 0-6.33 4h54.66a7 7 0 0 0-6.33-4zm-9.34 26a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-4.34a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-4.34a8.98 8.98 0 0 0 3.34-7h-2a7 7 0 0 1-7 7h-7a7 7 0 1 1 0-14h42a7 7 0 1 1 0 14h-9.34zM109 27a9 9 0 0 0-7.48 4H101a4 4 0 1 1 0-8h58a4 4 0 0 1 0 8h-.52a9 9 0 0 0-7.48-4h-42z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M39 115a8 8 0 1 0 0-16 8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm6-8a6 6 0 1 1-12 0 6 6 0 0 1 12 0zm-3-29v-2h8v-6H40a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v10H22l-1.33 4-.67 2h2.19L26 130h26l3.81-40H58l-.67-2L56 84H42v-6zm-4-4v10h2V74h8v-2h-8a2 2 0 0 0-2 2zm2 12h14.56l.67 2H22.77l.67-2H40zm13.8 4H24.2l3.62 38h22.36l3.62-38z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M129 92h-6v4h-6v4h-6v14h-3l.24 2 3.76 32h36l3.76-32 .24-2h-3v-14h-6v-4h-6v-4h-8zm18 22v-12h-4v4h3v8h1zm-3 0v-6h-4v6h4zm-6 6v-16h-4v19.17c1.6-.7 2.97-1.8 4-3.17zm-6 3.8V100h-4v23.8a10.04 10.04 0 0 0 4 0zm-6-.63V104h-4v16a10.04 10.04 0 0 0 4 3.17zm-6-9.17v-6h-4v6h4zm-6 0v-8h3v-4h-4v12h1zm27-12v-4h-4v4h3v4h1v-4zm-6 0v-8h-4v4h3v4h1zm-6-4v-4h-4v8h1v-4h3zm-6 4v-4h-4v8h1v-4h3zm7 24a12 12 0 0 0 11.83-10h7.92l-3.53 30h-32.44l-3.53-30h7.92A12 12 0 0 0 130 126z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M212 86v2h-4v-2h4zm4 0h-2v2h2v-2zm-20 0v.1a5 5 0 0 0-.56 9.65l.06.25 1.12 4.48a2 2 0 0 0 1.94 1.52h.01l7.02 24.55a2 2 0 0 0 1.92 1.45h4.98a2 2 0 0 0 1.92-1.45l7.02-24.55a2 2 0 0 0 1.95-1.52L224.5 96l.06-.25a5 5 0 0 0-.56-9.65V86a14 14 0 0 0-28 0zm4 0h6v2h-9a3 3 0 1 0 0 6H223a3 3 0 1 0 0-6H220v-2h2a12 12 0 1 0-24 0h2zm-1.44 14l-1-4h24.88l-1 4h-22.88zm8.95 26l-6.86-24h18.7l-6.86 24h-4.98zM150 242a22 22 0 1 0 0-44 22 22 0 0 0 0 44zm24-22a24 24 0 1 1-48 0 24 24 0 0 1 48 0zm-28.38 17.73l2.04-.87a6 6 0 0 1 4.68 0l2.04.87a2 2 0 0 0 2.5-.82l1.14-1.9a6 6 0 0 1 3.79-2.75l2.15-.5a2 2 0 0 0 1.54-2.12l-.19-2.2a6 6 0 0 1 1.45-4.46l1.45-1.67a2 2 0 0 0 0-2.62l-1.45-1.67a6 6 0 0 1-1.45-4.46l.2-2.2a2 2 0 0 0-1.55-2.13l-2.15-.5a6 6 0 0 1-3.8-2.75l-1.13-1.9a2 2 0 0 0-2.5-.8l-2.04.86a6 6 0 0 1-4.68 0l-2.04-.87a2 2 0 0 0-2.5.82l-1.14 1.9a6 6 0 0 1-3.79 2.75l-2.15.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.54 2.12l.19 2.2a6 6 0 0 1-1.45 4.46l-1.45 1.67a2 2 0 0 0 0 2.62l1.45 1.67a6 6 0 0 1 1.45 4.46l-.2 2.2a2 2 0 0 0 1.55 2.13l2.15.5a6 6 0 0 1 3.8 2.75l1.13 1.9a2 2 0 0 0 2.5.8zm2.82.97a4 4 0 0 1 3.12 0l2.04.87a4 4 0 0 0 4.99-1.62l1.14-1.9a4 4 0 0 1 2.53-1.84l2.15-.5a4 4 0 0 0 3.09-4.24l-.2-2.2a4 4 0 0 1 .97-2.98l1.45-1.67a4 4 0 0 0 0-5.24l-1.45-1.67a4 4 0 0 1-.97-2.97l.2-2.2a4 4 0 0 0-3.09-4.25l-2.15-.5a4 4 0 0 1-2.53-1.84l-1.14-1.9a4 4 0 0 0-5-1.62l-2.03.87a4 4 0 0 1-3.12 0l-2.04-.87a4 4 0 0 0-4.99 1.62l-1.14 1.9a4 4 0 0 1-2.53 1.84l-2.15.5a4 4 0 0 0-3.09 4.24l.2 2.2a4 4 0 0 1-.97 2.98l-1.45 1.67a4 4 0 0 0 0 5.24l1.45 1.67a4 4 0 0 1 .97 2.97l-.2 2.2a4 4 0 0 0 3.09 4.25l2.15.5a4 4 0 0 1 2.53 1.84l1.14 1.9a4 4 0 0 0 5 1.62l2.03-.87zM152 207a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm6 2a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-11 1a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-6 0a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm3-5a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-8 8a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm3 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm0 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4 7a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm5-2a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm5 4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4-6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm6-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-4-3a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm4-3a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-5-4a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm-24 6a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zm16 5a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm7-5a7 7 0 1 1-14 0 7 7 0 0 1 14 0zm86-29a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm19 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-14 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-25 1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm5 4a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm9 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm15 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm12-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-11-14a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-19 0a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm6 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-25 15c0-.47.01-.94.03-1.4a5 5 0 0 1-1.7-8 3.99 3.99 0 0 1 1.88-5.18 5 5 0 0 1 3.4-6.22 3 3 0 0 1 1.46-1.05 5 5 0 0 1 7.76-3.27A30.86 30.86 0 0 1 246 184c6.79 0 13.06 2.18 18.17 5.88a5 5 0 0 1 7.76 3.27 3 3 0 0 1 1.47 1.05 5 5 0 0 1 3.4 6.22 4 4 0 0 1 1.87 5.18 4.98 4.98 0 0 1-1.7 8c.02.46.03.93.03 1.4v1h-62v-1zm.83-7.17a30.9 30.9 0 0 0-.62 3.57 3 3 0 0 1-.61-4.2c.37.28.78.49 1.23.63zm1.49-4.61c-.36.87-.68 1.76-.96 2.68a2 2 0 0 1-.21-3.71c.33.4.73.75 1.17 1.03zm2.32-4.54c-.54.86-1.03 1.76-1.49 2.68a3 3 0 0 1-.07-4.67 3 3 0 0 0 1.56 1.99zm1.14-1.7c.35-.5.72-.98 1.1-1.46a1 1 0 1 0-1.1 1.45zm5.34-5.77c-1.03.86-2 1.79-2.9 2.77a3 3 0 0 0-1.11-.77 3 3 0 0 1 4-2zm42.66 2.77c-.9-.98-1.87-1.9-2.9-2.77a3 3 0 0 1 4.01 2 3 3 0 0 0-1.1.77zm1.34 1.54c.38.48.75.96 1.1 1.45a1 1 0 1 0-1.1-1.45zm3.73 5.84c-.46-.92-.95-1.82-1.5-2.68a3 3 0 0 0 1.57-1.99 3 3 0 0 1-.07 4.67zm1.8 4.53c-.29-.9-.6-1.8-.97-2.67.44-.28.84-.63 1.17-1.03a2 2 0 0 1-.2 3.7zm1.14 5.51c-.14-1.21-.35-2.4-.62-3.57.45-.14.86-.35 1.23-.63a2.99 2.99 0 0 1-.6 4.2zM275 214a29 29 0 0 0-57.97 0h57.96zM72.33 198.12c-.21-.32-.34-.7-.34-1.12v-12h-2v12a4.01 4.01 0 0 0 7.09 2.54c.57-.69.91-1.57.91-2.54v-12h-2v12a1.99 1.99 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-1.66-.88zM75 176c.38 0 .74-.04 1.1-.12a4 4 0 0 0 6.19 2.4A13.94 13.94 0 0 1 84 185v24a6 6 0 0 1-6 6h-3v9a5 5 0 1 1-10 0v-9h-3a6 6 0 0 1-6-6v-24a14 14 0 0 1 14-14 5 5 0 0 0 5 5zm-17 15v12a1.99 1.99 0 0 0 1.22 1.84 2 2 0 0 0 2.44-.72c.21-.32.34-.7.34-1.12v-12h2v12a3.98 3.98 0 0 1-5.35 3.77 3.98 3.98 0 0 1-.65-.3V209a4 4 0 0 0 4 4h16a4 4 0 0 0 4-4v-24c.01-1.53-.23-2.88-.72-4.17-.43.1-.87.16-1.28.17a6 6 0 0 1-5.2-3 7 7 0 0 1-6.47-4.88A12 12 0 0 0 58 185v6zm9 24v9a3 3 0 1 0 6 0v-9h-6z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M-17 191a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm19 9a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-14 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm-25 1a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm5 4a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm9 0a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm15 1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm12-2a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2H4zm-11-14a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-19 0a1 1 0 0 0 0 2h2a1 1 0 0 0 0-2h-2zm6 5a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 0 2h-2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1zm-25 15c0-.47.01-.94.03-1.4a5 5 0 0 1-1.7-8 3.99 3.99 0 0 1 1.88-5.18 5 5 0 0 1 3.4-6.22 3 3 0 0 1 1.46-1.05 5 5 0 0 1 7.76-3.27A30.86 30.86 0 0 1-14 184c6.79 0 13.06 2.18 18.17 5.88a5 5 0 0 1 7.76 3.27 3 3 0 0 1 1.47 1.05 5 5 0 0 1 3.4 6.22 4 4 0 0 1 1.87 5.18 4.98 4.98 0 0 1-1.7 8c.02.46.03.93.03 1.4v1h-62v-1zm.83-7.17a30.9 30.9 0 0 0-.62 3.57 3 3 0 0 1-.61-4.2c.37.28.78.49 1.23.63zm1.49-4.61c-.36.87-.68 1.76-.96 2.68a2 2 0 0 1-.21-3.71c.33.4.73.75 1.17 1.03zm2.32-4.54c-.54.86-1.03 1.76-1.49 2.68a3 3 0 0 1-.07-4.67 3 3 0 0 0 1.56 1.99zm1.14-1.7c.35-.5.72-.98 1.1-1.46a1 1 0 1 0-1.1 1.45zm5.34-5.77c-1.03.86-2 1.79-2.9 2.77a3 3 0 0 0-1.11-.77 3 3 0 0 1 4-2zm42.66 2.77c-.9-.98-1.87-1.9-2.9-2.77a3 3 0 0 1 4.01 2 3 3 0 0 0-1.1.77zm1.34 1.54c.38.48.75.96 1.1 1.45a1 1 0 1 0-1.1-1.45zm3.73 5.84c-.46-.92-.95-1.82-1.5-2.68a3 3 0 0 0 1.57-1.99 3 3 0 0 1-.07 4.67zm1.8 4.53c-.29-.9-.6-1.8-.97-2.67.44-.28.84-.63 1.17-1.03a2 2 0 0 1-.2 3.7zm1.14 5.51c-.14-1.21-.35-2.4-.62-3.57.45-.14.86-.35 1.23-.63a2.99 2.99 0 0 1-.6 4.2zM15 214a29 29 0 0 0-57.97 0h57.96z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-height: calc(1000vh - 70px);
    overflow: scroll;
   
}
.nav_main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    
 }

 .nav-menu{
    display: flex;
    width: 70%;
    
 }
 .nav_main ul {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
 .nav-menu-menu {
    display: flex;

}
.fa-home{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.433);
}

.search__flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.337);
    width: 270px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin: auto 10px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.search__flex__input{
    height: 30px;
    width: 190px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.search__flex__input__icon{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:  #607d8b;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav_main ul li{
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.cabeza {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(../assets/img/s.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center; 
    color: white; 
    font-size: 20px;  
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 3px black;
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

p.descriptio-p {
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn{
    display: flex;
}
.btn-btn{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    color:white;
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-btn:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.cards{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
.card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 1em);   
}
.btn-seguir-leyendo{
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn-seguir-leyendo:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.descripcion{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-align: start;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
}
.contenedor-titulo{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 55px;
}
img.img-recetas{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.card h2{
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.card a{
 display: block;
 text-align: end;
}
hr{
    
    padding: 3px 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.footer_footer{
    height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
}
.flex_footer-social a{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 3px;
}
.flex_footer-social h2{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.flex_footer-social-img{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.flex__p{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.flex_banner{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex_banner_noveades_img{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
.flex_novedades{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.flex_novedades p{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 90%;
}
.flex_novedades_link{
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(235, 7, 7, 0.487);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: rgba(208, 8, 8, 0.665);
    color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.494);
}
.flex_novedades_link:hover{
    color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.892);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/icon/fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.min.css">
    <title>COCINA CON TIFFA</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <nav class="nav_main">
                <a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
                    <ul class="nav-menu">
                        <div class="nav-menu-menu">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="productos.html">Productos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact-form.html">Contacto</a></li>
                        </div>    
                    </ul>           
                    <div class="search__flex">
                        <input class="search__flex__input" type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
                        <i class="fas fa-search search__flex__input__icon"></i>
                    </div>
            </nav> 
            <!-- <hr class="hr-nav">
            <div class="header-head">
                <header class="cabeza">
                <h2 class="header-h2">BIENVENIDOS</h2>
                <p class="descriptio-p">Somos una empresa que se dedica a vender viandas y subir aquellas recetas elaboradas que realizamos<p>
                    <div class="btn">
                        <a href="nosotros.html" class="btn-btn">Leer Mas</a>  
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div> -->
                <hr>  
                    <!-- <section class="cards">
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Receta de Pechuga de Pollo en Salsa de Albahaca</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas"src="assets/img/receta1.jfif" alt="">
                            <p class="descripcion">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis libero, deleniti molestias, fuga eveniet voluptate voluptatibus facilis mollitia quis culpa illum in vero non repudiandae repellendus. Quibusdam similique illum quos..
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="#">Seguir Leyendo</a> 
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                                <h2>Tamalitos de Extraviado y Hoja Santa</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas" src="assets/img/receta2.jfif" alt="">
                                <p class="descripcion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis libero, deleniti molestias, fuga eveniet voluptate voluptatibus facilis mollitia quis culpa illum in vero non repudiandae repellendus. Quibusdam similique illum quos..</p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="#">Seguir Leyendo</a>        
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Receta de Pechuga de Pollo enaaaa Salsa de Albahaca</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas" src="assets/img/receta3.jfif" alt="">
                            <p class="descripcion">
                                Ingredientes: Albahaca fresca 20 Gramos
                                Chalote 2 Unidades
                                Champiñones 100 Gramos...
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo"href="#">Seguir Leyendo</a>  
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Receta de Pechuga de Pollo en Salsa de Albahaca</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas" src="assets/img/receta4.jpg" alt="">
                            <p class="descripcion">
                                Ingredientes: Albahaca fresca 20 Gramos
                                Chalote 2 Unidades
                                Champiñones 100 Gramos...
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="">Seguir Leyendo</a>
                        </article>
                    </section>
                    <hr>
                    <section class="banner">
                        <aside class="flex_banner"> 
                            <img class="flex_banner_noveades_img" src="assets/img/novedades-en-instagram-1280x720.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="flex_novedades">
                                    <p>No te pierdas nuestras ultimas novedades en instagram</p>
                                    <a class="flex_novedades_link" href="https://instagram.com">Has Click Aqui!</a>
                                </div>    
                        </aside>
                    </section>
                    <hr>
                    <section class="cards">
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Receta de Pechuga de Pollo en Salsa de Albahaca</h2>
                             </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas"src="assets/img/receta1.jfif" alt="">
                            <p class="descripcion">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis libero, deleniti molestias, fuga eveniet voluptate voluptatibus facilis mollitia quis culpa illum in vero non repudiandae repellendus. Quibusdam similique illum quos..
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="#">Seguir Leyendo</a> 
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Tamalitos de Extraviado y Hoja Santa</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas" src="assets/img/receta2.jfif" alt="">
                                <p class="descripcion">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis libero, deleniti molestias, fuga eveniet voluptate voluptatibus facilis mollitia quis culpa illum in vero non repudiandae repellendus. Quibusdam similique illum quos..</p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="#">Seguir Leyendo</a>        
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Receta de Pechuga de Pollo en Salsa de Albahaca</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas" src="assets/img/receta3.jfif" alt="">
                            <p class="descripcion">
                                Ingredientes: Albahaca fresca 20 Gramos
                                Chalote 2 Unidades
                                Champiñones 100 Gramos...
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="#">Seguir Leyendo</a>  
                        </article>
                        <article class="card">
                            <div class="contenedor-titulo">
                            <h2>Receta de Pechuga de Pollo en Salsa de Albahaca</h2>
                            </div>
                            <img class="img-recetas" src="assets/img/receta4.jpg" alt="">
                            <p class="descripcion">
                                Ingredientes: Albahaca fresca 20 Gramos
                                Chalote 2 Unidades
                                Champiñones 100 Gramos...
                            </p>
                            <a class="btn-seguir-leyendo" href="">Seguir Leyendo</a>
                        </article>
                    </section>
                    <hr> -->
        </div>
                <footer class="footer_footer">
                    <ul class="flex_footer-social">
                        <h2 class="flex_footer-social-tittle">Social</h2>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flex_footer-social-img" src="assets/img/f.png" alt="">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flex_footer-social-img" src="assets/img/twt.png" alt="">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flex_footer-social-img" src="assets/img/ins.png" alt="">Instagram</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img class="flex_footer-social-img" src="assets/img/gt.png" alt="">GitHud</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="flex_footer-social-2">
                        <h2>Contacto</h2>
                    <li class="flex__p"><p>Tel: 15-555-555</p></li>
                    <li class=""><p>Email: naroasd@outlook.com</p></li>
                    <li class=""><p>Email: assadasdas@hotmail.com</p></li>
                    <li class=""><p>Tel: 11-2323-323</p></li>
                    </ul>  
                    <ul class="flex_footer-social-2">
                        <h2>Direccion</h2>
                    <li class=""><p>Lanús</p></li>
                    <li class=""><p>Banfield</p></li>
                    <li class=""><p>Lomas de Zamora</p></li>
                    <li class=""><p>Temperley</p></li>
                    </ul>  
            </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Para que podamos ayudarle, por favor, enseñe el código involucrado (en su caso, el HTML donde está el div o elemento deseado y el trozo CSS donde está lo del sticky footer). Así podremos saber qué ocurre y ayudarle. Un enlace al repositorio entero de GitHub no ayuda mucho. ¡Gracias!

Comment: La pregunta debe servirle a otros en el futuro con la misma duda. No debe depender de que borrer tu repo o tu cuenta github. Tampoco se trata de navegar N archivos en tu proyecto. Debe haber un ejemplo mínimo verificable EN la pregunta. Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: estás usando `max-height` en vez de `min-height` en el estilo del contenedor.

Comment: Gracias, creo que era eso porque ahora quedo abajo y al agregar contenido simpre se posiciona ahi. Mala mia jajajajaja

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas estar calculando altura para colocar el `stickyFooter` si tu elemento con clase `contenedor` ya tiene una altura y un ancho determinado por ti.

Simplemente toma el elemento `<footer>` y agrega un `bottom 0` y `position fixed` de la siguiente forma:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #808080;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, igual la idea no es degarlo en fixed, sino que cuando agrege contenido el footer quede abajo siempre. No se si me explico en mi poca experiencia en esto. Dspues tengo otro problema, que al pasar de Home a Productos por ejemplo el navbar es mas grande...

Comment: Favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/483231/edit) con lo que necesitas hacer, todos los problemas que tienes y lo que haz intentado para resolverlos, de esta forma la comunidad podra ayudarte mejor.